# fill in a path with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a visual graph for a web page using rectangle and the path line. That is all done and now I wish to color the top one color, and the bottom another. I tried making the whole thing red and overwriting the bottom with green(horrible combo I know, but they are just for testing purposes). It makes the whole thing red but I don't see any green.
So my question is, how can I color in the bottom differently form the top?

```
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #D3D3D3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.                 </canvas>
    <script>
        var theCanvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var theContext=theCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var rectangle=theCanvas.getContext("2d");

        var sales = new Array();
        sales[0] = 52;
        sales[1] = 48;
        sales[2] = 74;
        sales[3] = 31;
        sales[4] = 47;
        sales[5] = 25;
        sales[6] = 67;
        sales[7] = 78;
        sales[8] = 45;
        sales[9] = 75;
        sales[10] = 85;

        var scalar = 10;
        var width = 10;
        var height = 10;
        var spacing = 10
        var y = height * scalar;

        rectangle.rect(0, 0, (width * scalar), y);
        rectangle.fillStyle="red";
        rectangle.fill();
        rectangle.stroke();

        theContext.beginPath();
        theContext.moveTo(0, y);
        theContext.lineTo(0, (y - sales[0]));
        theContext.stroke();
        for(var i = -1; i < sales.length; ++i)
        {
            theContext.moveTo((spacing * i), (y - sales[i]));
            theContext.lineTo(spacing * (i + 1), (y - sales[i + 1]));
            theContext.stroke();
        }
        theContext.moveTo((width * scalar), (y - sales[10]));
        theContext.lineTo((width * scalar), y);
        theContext.stroke();
        theContext.moveTo((width * scalar), y);
        theContext.lineTo(0, y);
        theContext.stroke();
        theContext.moveTo(0, y);
        theContext.lineTo(0, (y - sales[0]));
        theContext.closePath();
        theContext.fillStyle="green";//doesn't seem to work!
        theContext.fill();
        theContext.stroke();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is breaking up the polygon because it uses too many `moveTo()`. If you break up the path there won't be anything to fill as there are only left non-continuous lines.

Try to exclude them like this:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/zk4gw/)**

```
theContext.beginPath();
theContext.moveTo(0, y);
theContext.lineTo(0, (y - sales[0]));
//theContext.stroke();
for(var i = -1; i < sales.length; ++i)
{
    //theContext.moveTo((spacing * i), (y - sales[i]));
    theContext.lineTo(spacing * (i + 1), (y - sales[i + 1]));
    //theContext.stroke();
}
//theContext.moveTo((width * scalar), (y - sales[10]));
theContext.lineTo((width * scalar), y);
theContext.stroke();

//theContext.moveTo((width * scalar), y);
theContext.lineTo(0, y);
//theContext.stroke();
//theContext.moveTo(0, y);
theContext.lineTo(0, (y - sales[0]));
theContext.closePath();
theContext.fillStyle="green";  //works!
theContext.fill();
theContext.stroke();
```

or cleaned up:

```
theContext.beginPath();
theContext.moveTo(0, y);
theContext.lineTo(0, (y - sales[0]));

for(var i = -1; i < sales.length; ++i) {
    theContext.lineTo(spacing * (i + 1), (y - sales[i + 1]));
}
theContext.lineTo((width * scalar), y);
theContext.stroke();

theContext.lineTo(0, y);
theContext.lineTo(0, (y - sales[0]));
theContext.closePath();
theContext.fillStyle="green";  //works!
theContext.fill();
theContext.stroke();
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize moving it broke it up, but I suppose it makes a lot more sense that it continues from the last draw point.